# Want to post a photo on this month's contest, BUT

Tags: discussion, support

I want to post a photo on this month's contest, OOPS, but to my shame, I don't know how. Actually, I've had decent photos for all the contests, but it is just now that I have decided to ask for help.

The photos were originally on film, actual film.  I can get them scanned into my e-mail, but what do I do then?

HELP!

Comment: Is your problem getting the image onto your device? Or from the device onto TGO?

Comment: @JIMMYPlay Getting the image from my computer e-mail onto TGO.

Comment: If all else fails you can email the pictures to me and I can upload them

Comment: @Charlie Brumbaugh THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

There should be a way on your email to download the image onto your computer. This could be right clicking on it and finding the download button in the menu, or clicking on it and finding a download button when it pulls up some form of larger version of the image. From there you should go in to put in your answer.

To add an image there is an icon with a mountain and a sun in the top bar where all of the text editing tools are. This should allow you to access the files on your computer where you can find and select the desired image then simply click the button that says accept, ol, done, or something like that and then you should be able to continue writing your response after it is in.

Comment: Thanks, JIMMYPlay, but it is "like you would do normally" part that I have forgotten, because transferring a pic to TGO is not something that I do normally.

Comment: I edited is that helpful?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.